# How to plot two variables using two Y axis values on one bar chart

Tags: python, plot

I have these two variables:

```
top_genres = df.name.value_counts()[:5].plot(kind='bar')

top_lang = lang.original_language.value_counts()[:5].plot(kind='bar')
```

These variables are plotted on two separate barcharts.
How can I plot them on one using two Y axis values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `twinx()` function. Check [here](https://www.studytonight.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-twin-axes).